# Choose the name of Image from Bitmap

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap

I'm saving some image from a Bitmap in gallery, and it works fine, but It's saving with some random name, and I don't know how to change the name of the image before save it. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
public void save(View v) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if (mBitmap == null) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    tempDir = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/";
    cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    directory = cw.getDir(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    prepareDirectory();
    current = osID + ".png";
    mypath = new File(directory, current);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                v.draw(canvas);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);

                byte[] bytes = getByteArray(mBitmap);

                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();

                String pathPhotoSelected = IOUtil.getRealPathFromURI(CaptureSignature.this, getImageUri(CaptureSignature.this, mBitmap));

                Log.d("PATH", pathPhotoSelected);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, osID, null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

public static String getRealPathFromURI(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int indexData = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(indexData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}

private boolean prepareDirectory() {
    try {
        if (makedirs()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```